# Get the word that comes after a certain word in java

Tags: java, json, file, file-io

I have an info file that has the following structure:

> `{"captcha_set": "accounts.snapchat.com_2015-03-09_17-13-24", "correct_answer": [5, 8], "desc": {"keyword": "beer", "text": "Select all beer below. A sample image is on the right."}}`

I tried to convert this info file as a JSON object to get the value of the `"keyword"`, but it didn't convert since when I printed the JSON object there is no content in it.

The code I wrote for that is the following:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static void walk(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File[] list = new File(path).listFiles();
    if (list == null) return;
    for (File f : list) {
        if ( f.getName().equals("info.txt")) {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString()); 

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb);
            System.out.println(jsonObj+"\n");
        } else {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

The result was an empty curly brackets `{}`.

So I'm not sure about the other options to get the value of the  "keyword", how can I read the word that comes after the "keyword" in each info file?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and let us know what problem you are facing.

Comment: @BheshGurung I edited the question, thank you.

Comment: There’s no content? Are you *sure* you’re actually reading the file in?

Comment: @Bohemian yes when I printed the file the content appears in the results but when I print it after making it as a Json object only { } appears in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass a `String` to the constructor:

```
new JSONObject(sb.toString())
```

to invoke the `public JSONObject(String source)` constructor, which as per its [javadoc](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String-) will:

> Construct a JSONObject from a source JSON text string

which is what you want.

You coded:

```
new JSONObject(sb)
```

but passing a non-String object to the constructor invokes the `public JSONObject(Object bean)` constructor, which as per the [javadoc](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.Object-) will:

> Construct a JSONObject from an Object using bean getters.

And `StringBuilder` has no getters, so you got an empty object.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked with me! If you allow me to ask you another question:  `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                      JSONObject desc = jsonObj.getJSONObject("desc");
                      JSONObject hint = desc.getJSONObject("keyword");
    
                    System.out.println(hint+"\n");` it gave this error: `Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["keyword"] is not a JSONObject.` How can I get it then ?

Comment: @User505 Try `desc.getString("keyword");`. The value at `"keyword"` is a `String`, not a `JSONObject` (which ihas key/value pairs like a Map).

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you, brilliant! it worked with me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @User505 No problem. Your happiness is thanks enough :)